# Invalid Syntax error pandas series

Tags: pandas, series

I am starting out with pandas on jupyter notebook. In the error message, there is a ^ below the = operator, but I cannot see the problem. What's missing?  thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
data2 = ([1, 2, 3, 4],  index = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

s = pd.Series(data2)
print(s.shape)
```

This is the error:

```
File "<ipython-input-30-57c99bd7e494>", line 4
    data2 = ([1, 2, 3, 4],  index = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `pd.Series([...])` is not equivalent to `x = ([...]); pd.Series(x)`. Argument syntax can't be extracted out and saved to a variable.

Comment: I think best you can do is save it as a dict: `data2 = dict(data=[1, 2, 3, 4],  index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])`  and pass to the Series constructor: `pd.Series(**data2)`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

There proper way to do this is, separate variables for data and index:

```
import pandas as pd
data2 = [1,2,3,4]
index = ['a','b','c','d']

s = pd.Series(data2,index)
print(s.shape)
```

Or as ayhan points our you could unpack a dictionary with `**`:

```
data2 = dict(data=[1,2,3,4], index=['a','b','c','d'])
s = pd.Series(**data2)
print(s.shape)
```

Comment: it doesn't have to be `dict`, it may be `tuple` as well:  `s = pd.Series(*data2)`